# Проблемы с pjax на codeigniter

Tags: jquery, pjax, codeigniter

Доброго времени суток.
На демо pjax работает нормально, но когда я попытался его поставить на свой сайт, он отказывался работать, т.е обработка идет, но перезагрузка страницы все равно происходит
использую imagecms(Codeigniter) + twitter bootstrap

Я полностью скопировал демо на свой сайт(включая все либы) и все равно не работает! Это просто мистика...(Хотя в админке pjax работает)

Если есть какие ни будь идеи, то пожалуйста озвучьте :)

Comment: И в консоли никаких ошибок нет?

Comment: К сожалению нет(если бы были то уже знал бы что и где копать)...Пробовал конечно же $.pjax() напрямую в консоль вбивать, мельком видел ответ от сервера, readystate: 1 был...а потом перезагрузка страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;